# Stitch room recordings into one image

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, homography, image-stitching

I have two recordings from security cameras which are located on opposite corners. Each of the cameras has a dead spot (image attached).

I am looking for a technique in python that allows creating a map of the objects in the room space based on these two cameras' views.
Can you please suggest something?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Problem definition**

Given two images from the same scene, stitch these images side-by-side by finding common parts (features) that overlap with each other.

**Approach**

In theory, the steps followed to solve the problem are as follows:

1. Detect feature points using Harris corner detection.
2. Create key-point descriptors by creating patches around them
3. Estimate key-point matches based on the Euclidean distance
4. Perform RANSAC to find the affine transformation matrix
5. Warp and apply geometric transformation

For the abovementioned steps you can refer to the [OpenCV tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d27/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_feature2d.html) and other libraries that might come in use for some specific step [`sklearn.feature`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.feature.html) module used on the feature extraction step.

Also, you can find many image stitching projects on github in case you don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: you're supposed to estimate the transformations _once_ (not for every frame) because the cameras don't move. -- you should use SIFT or AKAZE or other decent feature descriptors. a corner detector just detects corners, it does not give matchable features. "create patches" is non-specific. -- the distance metric for matching depends on the type of descriptor. euclidean is for "floating point". for binary descriptors, it's hamming distance. -- you don't use ransac explicitly. you use findHomography. -- it's not affine, it's perspective. -- do not copy random "stitching" code. most often it's bad.

Comment: generally you should find questions you can answer from experience, so your answer isn't as shaky as this one. from among those tutorials, the most relevant is the last one because with just a little additional work (that isn't explained there) it can do the warping from the second picture into the first picture... but none of that explains good approaches for blending those two pictures. there is one tutorial that uses laplacian pyramids for blending. might be worth a look.

Comment: wow, thanks so much! very clear description.